# Dependency issue while installing gazebo packages

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to install gazebo to Ubuntu 20.04 as part of pixhawk4 development setup. I ran the ubuntu.sh script provided in the standard installation procedure.
I get the following error and my installation stops due to dependencies issue of libignition-transport8-dev library. Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue.

Error on terminal

> Preparing to unpack .../205-libignition-transport8-log-dev_8.4.0-2~focal_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking libignition-transport8-log-dev:amd64 (8.4.0-2~focal)

> 8dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-p3JQ9B/205-libignition-transport8-log-dev_8.4.0-2~focal_amd64.deb (--unpack):  trying to >overwrite '/usr/include/ignition/transport8/gz/transport/log.hh', which is also in package libignition-transport8-core-dev:amd64 8.4.0-2~focal**

> Selecting previously unselected package libgazebo11-dev:amd64.
> Preparing to unpack .../208-libgazebo11-dev_11.12.0-1~focal_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking libgazebo11-dev:amd64 (11.12.0-1~focal) ...

> Errors were encountered while processing:
> /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-p3JQ9B/205-libignition-transport8-log-dev_8.4.0-2~focal_amd64.deb

> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28569/dependency-issue-while-installing-gazebo-packages/) by [eigenS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/116268/eigens/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chuckclaunch](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/49722/chuckclaunch/) on 2022-11-19**:
I am seeing the same issue since the 8.4.0 release a couple of days ago.  Identical error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-G02N6D/349-libignition-transport8-log-dev_8.4.0-2~focal_amd64.deb (--unpack):   
trying to overwrite '/usr/include/ignition/transport8/gz/transport/log.hh', which is also in package libignition-transport8-core-dev:amd64 8.4.0-2~focal
```

**Comment by [eigenS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/116268/eigens/) on 2022-11-20**:
Could it be a bug? Do we need to report it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like someone reported as a bug: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-transport/issues/371

---

Originally posted by [chuckclaunch](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/49722/chuckclaunch/) with karma: 16 on 2022-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1